# What is the difference between the error "not found" and the error "command not found" are they the same?

Tags: apt, rm, dpkg, command-not-found

In [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/673758/rm-not-found-by-apt-cron-and-others/673858?noredirect=1#comment975352_673858) the user is getting the error "not found". I  realized that the error is "not found" instead of "command not found".

Are these two errors different? I'm not sure if I've just never paid attention to this before or if this is different.

Here's an example:

```
/etc/cron.daily/apt:
/etc/cron.daily/apt: 91: /etc/cron.daily/apt: date: not found
/etc/cron.daily/apt: 97: /etc/cron.daily/apt: rm: not found
/etc/cron.daily/apt: 448: /etc/cron.daily/apt: pidof: not found
xargs: rm: No such file or directory
/etc/cron.daily/apt: 176: /etc/cron.daily/apt: date: not found
/etc/cron.daily/apt: 176: /etc/cron.daily/apt: date: not found
```

Comment: To fix this error try `apt-get install coreutils`  It's also useful to use `dpkg -S` using the missing command as the argument.

Comment: @eyoung100 thanks, I used `apt-file search` and noticed `bin` and `date` are both part of `coreutils` and `pidof` is part of `sysvinit-utils` it's always cool to have more than one way to get the info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the difference between how `bash` and `dash` handle cases when a command is not found.

In `bash`, there is a function named `command_not_found_handle` :

```
$ type command_not_found_handle 
command_not_found_handle is a function
command_not_found_handle () 
{ 
    if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
        /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1";
        return $?;
    else
        if [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
            /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1";
            return $?;
        else
            printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" 1>&2;
            return 127;
        fi;
    fi
}
```

So in `bash` :

```
$ foobar
foobar: command not found
```

In case of `dash`, there is no such function defined and we get :

```
$ foobar
dash: 1: foobar: not found
```

As Ubuntu uses `dash` as the default shell for internal operations so when `dash` is parsing some script it would show its own format.

Comment: Awesome, I have seen this so many times before but just now noticed there was a difference, thanks!

Comment: @mchid Its basically the difference in response to the same event..